# Is data subsampling appropriate for hyperparameter optimisation?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, hyperparameter-tuning

Fundamentally, under what circumstance is it reasonable to do HPO only on a subsample of the training set?

I am using Population Based Training to optimise hparameters for a sequence model. My dataset consists of 20M sequences and was wondering if it would make sense to optimise on a subsample due to restricted budget.

Comment: Does this post answers your question ? [Is sampling a valid way to reduce complexity?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/85120/is-sampling-a-valid-way-to-reduce-complexity)

Comment: Thanks @etiennedm, I am not very sure if this applies to supervised learning as in my case? I have updated my question to make my problem more clear.

Comment: That is true, in your case, you could benefit from the fact that it is supervised learning by ensuring to keep the classes distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Your subsample has to be representative of your original dataset.

To do so, as you are in a supervised case, I would get a random subsample that keeps the classes distribution (for instance getting randomly 40% of each class).

*Note*
If you have classes with too few examples, I would also try not to sample them. Risk is even with random sampling you could loose information when a cluster is too small. Plus, if your problem is computation time, that won't be a problem to keep the too small clusters while sampling the bigs.

Comment: Sure that makes sense and that has been my strategy. However, I am not sue that a config that applies to 1M datapoints generalises to 15M. I would expect it to be correct if model performance for 1M is the same for 10M (same signals), but that is just not the case in most of the cases.

Comment: I just got your point, you'd like to retrain a final model with your 20M points keeping the HP of an optimisation made with 1M, is that correct ? In my answer I thought you wanted to do HP tuning to train a model on 1M and then use it on the 20M points